# Declare variables programmatically?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a bunch of variables like this:

```
function l(){
    var a1 = 2,
        a2 = 4,
        a3 = 6,
        a4 = 8,
          .
          .
        a20 = 40;
}
```

But this is taking too many lines, and I am searching for a way to do it smarter. This is what I have come up:

```
function l(){
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        var ("a"+i) = 2*i;
    }
}
```

But it probably won't work, <s>and if it works (it does not) the variables will still be inside the `for` scope.</s> Any ideas?

```
window["a"+i] or eval(...)
```

These don't work because I don't want them to be in the global scope.

Usually an Array would be fine, but I am just experimenting if this is possible in JavaScript. Maybe in the future I would encounter something like this.

Comment: Just a note: they will not be in the for scope--everything in JavaScript is function scoped.

Comment: i would suggest using an array

Comment: If you really don't want to use an array for whatever reason, and you dont want to use window because of global scope, just replace window with some other var...

Comment: @Derek they are only scoped within the for statement if you use `let` instead of `var`.  But `let` is part of ES6.  It's in Firefox now, though.  But Josh is right, they are function scoped, not block-scoped because you used `var`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't do this. Do. Not. Do. This. **Use an array.**

---

Given the trouble you're having *creating* them programmatically, how do you think you'd *refer* to them programmatically?

Comment: You do have a point. So I guess creating variables programmatically is not possible in JavaScript then. (And probably not useful in any case.)

Comment: It can be quite useful for DSLs. Then, using eval (as Akhil Sekharan described) is the way to go. It allows to extend the local scope without polluting the global one.

Comment: @Otts 100% agree. That's why I needed this too. This answer isn't an answer to the question, it's a comment about intentions. I don't see the problem with referring to the programatically using Akhil Sekharan's `eval` method. You just refer to them like you would with normal variables.

Comment: Be sure to understand all the security issues surrounding eval if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess its better for you to go with an array, like:

```
function l(){
    var a = [];
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        a[i] = 2*i;
    }
}
```

Or if you really want the long list of variables, try this. But its using eval()

```
function l(){
    var js = '';
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        js += 'var a'+i+' = '+2*i+';'
    }
    eval (js);
}
```

Comment: Why `new Array()` instead of `[]`? And why is there _any_ reason to use `eval` here at all?

Comment: It's not recommended. Only if he want a long list of variables like a1,a2,a3.....

Comment: Developing a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and this is exactly what I needed! This should be marked as the correct answer given that it actually answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, I think using a object is a good idea.

```
var scope = {}
for (var i=1;i<=20;i++) {
  scope['a'+i] = 'stuff';   
}
```

The result will be you have a `scope` object that contain every newly create variable you want!